# Tips and tricks to make NX server more stable

Tags: linux, fedora, nx, freenx

My shop has been using the FreeNX server on Fedora 11 for a while now and mostly getting good results, especially with performance, but we have some annoying problems with client connections.  There are two main issues:

1. Client sessions sometimes freeze after a long time (seems to be at least 2 hours of having the session active)
2. We often have to make multiple attempts to start a new client session, especially if a previous session was suspended rather than terminated.  In qwuite a few cases, we've had to restart the NX server to get around this.

Our NX server configuration is the default except that we've enabled logging level 7 to /var/log/nxserver.log, and set the font server to "unix:/7100" so that it uses xfs.

Does anyone have any ideas for making things more stable ?

Comment: I've had weird issues with NX as well. I went back to regular ssh X forwarding, and haven't bothered with NX since.

Comment: @Ignacio: were your 'NX' problems *'FreeNX'* or *'NoMachine NX'* problems?

Comment: pipitas they were !M problems, as in certain keys would be mismapped, and the client would crash when switching workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [neatx](http://code.google.com/p/neatx/) as FreeNX tends to be unstable and is less actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving to a newer, or at least better supported, distribution.

At this point (March '11) the "current" Fedora Core is 14, 11 is somewhat dated.

We run the FreeNX server on CentOS 5.x with good success.  Yes, this base is also dated ('06 or '07) but RedHat is more actively porting fixes to this distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the NX client, which client are you using ?

If you use the nomachine client, it might cause problems since you also use the freenx server, which isn't as up-to-date as the nomachine NX server. Maybe a rollback of the client to a know working version could help ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like it noted that I haven't noticed any of these issues with the commercial nx server or client. Freenx on the other hand has had numerous issues, and neatx although a good alternative had some annoying quirks as well. If its a production machine it might be worth going the commercial route on this one.